# how to execute independant javaexec tasks

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, javaexec-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle project titled 'FunctionalityMaintainer' I am trying to execute two JavaExec tasks in a build.gradle, but independantly. 
The following is the structure of my build.gradle

```
task(findPattern, dependsOn:'classes', type:JavaExec){
main = 'org.package.somepackage1.PatternMatcher'
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
args = [project.getProperty('baseDir'), project.getProperty('playGroundWorkspace')]
}

task(deleteZip, dependsOn:'classes', type:JavaExec){
main = 'org.package.somepackage2.ZipDeleter'
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
args = [project.getProperty('zipPath')]
}
```

If I execute say deleteZip task, with the following command -

```
gradle deleteZip -PzipPath='D:/PathtoZip'
```

It fails with the error,

```
could not get unknown property 'baseDir' for root project 'FunctionalityMaintainer' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When using `project.getProperty()` Gradle will throw `MissingPropertyException` if the property is not found (in your case you don't provide value for `basedir` and `playGroundWorkspace`, that's why the build fails)  You should rather use `project.findProperty()` method if you have some optional properties in your script, or initialize these properties with default values.

Comment: yes, you are right. Thank you so much. :) I gave default values to all the properties and now it's working